# calling nested sections in Mongo DB

Tags: python, mongodb, api

I am working with a mongo database shell in python and am trying to call on it to find the eastern, western, northern, and southern most cities in a database I made from an API from google. I have so far been unable to call upon the latitude for it though. 
Here is a sample of a line in my database

```
{'location': {'lat': 39.90419989999999, 'lng': 116.4073963}, 'City': 'Beijing', 'Country': 'China', '_id': ObjectId('5add5c0051420a4fb4811209')}
```

and here is the code I have so far to try and call the eastern most city

```
mongo_print(db.cities.find().sort({'lat':1}).limit(1))
```

Comment: you should sort on `'location.lat'` instead of `'lat'`

Comment: I just tried that but I got the error "TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list"

Answer (score 0):

Generally with python, you will have to mention the ordering like this, let see if it works.

mongo_print(db.cities.find().sort({'lat':1,pymongo.ASCENDING = 1}).limit(1))